# Infinity loop when using useEffect while try to update children component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop, use-effect

I am trying to update components when the parent component passes down the change to the children through props, so I create a test program like so

PARENT COMPONENT

```
   function Parent(props){
     const [newCount, setNewCount] = useState(0)
     const handleClick = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        setNewCount(count+1)
     }
     return <div>
                 <button className='btn btn-primary' type='submit' onClick={handleClick}>parent</button>
                 <Test newCount = {count}/>
            </div>
}
```

CHILDREN COMPONENT

```
function Test(props){
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    const {newCount} = props
    useEffect(()=>{
        setCount(count + 1) ### marked line
    },[newCount, count])
    return <button type='submit'>{count}</button>
}
```

whenever the parent's button got clicked the children will be re-rendered base on the "newCount" value passed from its parent. I can understand that the line marked with "###" will cause an infinite loop, but what make me confuse is if I replace `setCount(count+1)` with `setCount(newCount+1)` then I don't get infinite loop anymore. Can some want help me explain why? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added count as a dependency to useEffect which in itself updates count, so the useEffect gets triggered in a loop

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setCount(count + 1) ### marked line
},[newCount, count]); // problem due to use of count here
```

When you change to `setCount(newCount + 1)`, you would be removing the dependency count from useEffect and hence it no longer causes an infinite loop

Since you want to update the child state based on parent, you must actually be using

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setCount(newCount) ### marked line
},[newCount]);
```

However you can directly use the count value from props and update the same by passing an updater function from parent as props without the need to copy into local state

**P.S.** Probably its just a typo in post, but in the parent you need to use `newCount` and not `count` while updating state since count is not defined in parent

```
const handleClick = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    setNewCount(newCount+1)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In you child component from useEffect remove count and i hope it will help

```
function Test(props){
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const {newCount} = props
  useEffect(()=>{
    setCount(count + 1) ### marked line
  },[newCount])
  return <button type='submit'>{count}</button>
}
```